# New window/tab can't be closed via script within the new window/tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 pages. One is the main page, and one is a form page. When I click a button on the main page I want the form to popup as a new tab/window and when the user is done they can click a "close" button on the new Form page to close the window and return to the main page.

I am opening a new window with the following javascript:

```
// This javascript is on the MAIN page
window.open("http://www.baseurl.com/form", "UserForm");
```

I have a "close" button on the poppup that I want to use to close the new window and return to my Mian page. Like this:

```
// This javascript is on the FORM page
$(document).on("click", "a#close_form", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.close;
}
```

The `close` button won't work even though the form page was opened with Javascript.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`close` is a method - you need to call it by adding `()` to the end.

```
$(document).on("click", "a#close_form", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.close(); // < added brackets to call the function
}
```

Your current code was simply getting the reference to the function and not executing it.

Comment: Well played. Thanks for the quick response.